How to travel along the curve
Here is the problem: given a list of 2D points which are not sorted.
The goal is to find the starting/end point and travel along the curve once. Consider a spiral, you are at a random point on spiral, how do we reach the middle point where it starts/end point and then travel once.
Also, the problem can be thought as finding a travel direction along the curve.
Can we do this in a generalized non heuristic way ?
One way which I can think is to find connected components and the place where neighbours is one, that point is an endpoint but then I was stuck at how to find connected components without keeping some heuristic.


Seems to me the problem statement is to find an ordering $P_{1},...,P{n}$ such that for each $k=1,...,n-1$, the line segment $\overline{P_{k}P_{k+1}}$ contains no other point $P_{i}$ such that $i\neq k,k+1$. Yes? Or do you insist additionally that the curve be non-intersecting?

@TonyDean Curve might be intersecting. The main idea is that the points represent waypoints of a car travelling and I am interested in finding out the travel direction, given that waypoints may be out of order
